# ActiveMerchant Get Braintree ClientToken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, braintree, activemerchant

I am trying to use ActiveMerchant with Braintree Dropin UI and I am unable to find the correct methods to create the client token to pass to the JavaScript SDK. My current setup is:

```
# config/environments/development.rb
# ActiveMerchant configuration.
ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
config.gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::BraintreeGateway.new(
  merchant_id: '',
  public_key: '',
  private_key: ''
)
```

And I have a controller that needs to send back a client token as part of an API request:

```
# app/controllers/v1/orders_controller.rb
def token
  @client_token = ...GENERATE CLIENT TOKEN...
  respond_with @client_token
end
```

I just don't know how to generate this token through the ActiveMerchant API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you have more questions, I suggest you [email our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

ActiveMerchant currently isn't compatible with v.zero. To use the Drop-In UI or any other v.zero features, you'll need to use the Braintree ruby client library directly. See the [Braintree "Getting Started" Guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/start/overview) for instructions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This has saved me a lot of time pulling my hair out to only end in disappointment. Will just use the Braintree SDK instead.